# how to jump body at specific point and return back andengine

Tags: andengine

i want to jump my enemy body on screen touch, i am doing something like this but after touching on screen body keep jumping upward.i want to stop body at specific point and then return back to tha starting point...in short i want jumping body
please help.thanks in advance

```
        @Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    playerBody.setLinearVelocity(0, -1*2);


return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `applyForce()` for this purpose.

```
        @Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    playerBody.applyForce(0,-10);


return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.
my player is in center at bottom.i want to jump up, in -x direction.i am doing this, but body start rotation fastly and go down instead of going up.

        'playerBody.applyForce(0f,100f, playerBody.getWorldCenter().x-20,playerBody.getWorldCenter().y);'